# locking multiple objects: scenarios and risks

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, concurrentdictionary

I want to load some objects from database and cache them. It's simple:

```
public class Dal {
    public Entity GetEntity(int id) {
        var cacheKey = string.Format(".cache.key.{0}", id);
        var item = Cache.Get(cacheKey) as Entity;
        if(item == null) {
            item = LoadEntityFromDatabase(id);
            Cache.Add(cacheKey, item);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

It's pretty simple. But when multiple threads want to access `Dal.GetEntity`, I want to `lock` an object which is bounded to `id`. The scenario I can think about is something like this:

```
public class Dal {

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>
        _locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();

    public Entity GetEntity(int id) {
        var cacheKey = string.Format(".cache.key.{0}", id);
        var item = Cache.Get(cacheKey) as Entity;
        if(item == null) {
            var lockObject = _locks.GetOrAdd(id, new object());            
            lock (lockObject) {
                if(item == null) {
                    // all exceptions are handled in this block.
                    item = LoadEntityFromDatabase(id); 
                    Cache.Add(cacheKey, item);
                }
            }
            // * Here is the removing problem: 
            _locks.TryRemove(id, out lockObject);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

The goal is: I want to lock and `id`, when one thread is fetching it from database. Actually I want prevent requesting an object from database twice. It seems to work, I think. But I'm not exactly a multithread programmer, nor a `lock`-guy. So, the question is: what risks am I taking with this scenario?

Also, I have this problem: how to prevent dictionary from getting larger and larger? As you can see, - where I marked with a `*` -, I'm trying to remove used items with `TryRemove` method. But It seems a stupid move: *What if it tries to remove an object, while the object is locked with another thread?* Am I right?

Comment: If I were you, I'd not even bother to remove the lock objects. How much memory it is gonna take? Are you running in memory constrained environment? If not just leave it as it is.

Comment: There is a lot of requests and `id`s. think about millions.

Comment: It seems that you are only locking on write, not on read. What happens if someone requests the same key before calling `Add`?

Comment: Reading seems not to be a problem. Is it? I'm checking if the `item` is `null` in `lock` block. Do you think it is not good?

Comment: `if(item == null)` inside the lock block will always be true. It will never be false. Your code is broken.

Comment: `item` will remain `null` as you try to get the item only once, outside the `lock`. If someone trys to `Cache.Get` before the item is actually added to the dictionary, it will result in getting the same item twice.

Comment: What's the benefit to avoid reading entity from database twice? Since you're trying to fetch entity by id, the time your code will spend to read entity from DB won't be significant.

Comment: @Dennis there is a lot of requests to database which I want to reduce them

Comment: @Javad_Amiry: "lot of" - how much? Have you measured DB server load? Why have you decided, that this is bottle-neck? Sorry, but it looks like premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advice you not to mix ConcurrentDictionary and locks.
Either work with locks and a normal Dictionary or work with a ConcurrentDictionary and lock-free only.
You are currently risking races - e.g. when 3 threads act on the same record. A thread removes the old lock - B thread uses the old lock and C thread creates a new lock, so that B and C might work in parallel.

Comment: OP isn't locking the dictionary. I guess you overlooked or misunderstood.

Comment: The code is quite generic - but I think that there is a potential for races with the current code if you work with 3 threads on 1 item.A removes old lock, B uses old lock and C creates new lock.

Comment: OP tries to "lock" entity ID to prevent another thread from attempt to fill cache, using the same ID. He doesn't lock `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: A lock-free ConcurrentDictionary is used to manage locks - does this sound ok or not?

Comment: "does this sound ok or not?" doesn't matter for this question. Your answer doesn't makes any sense. You didn't answered any of OP's questions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that. (not tested);

```
public class Dal
{
    private sealed class Locker
    {
        private static readonly object DictionaryLocker = new object();
        private static readonly Dictionary<int, Locker>
            Locks = new Dictionary<int, Locker>();

        private readonly object _lockerObject;
        private int _num;

        private Locker()
        {
            _num = 0;
            _lockerObject = new object();
        }

        public static object StartLock(int id)
        {
            Locker locker;
            lock (DictionaryLocker)
            {
                if (!Locks.TryGetValue(id, out locker))
                {
                    locker = new Locker();
                    Locks.Add(id, locker);
                }
                ++locker._num;
            }

            return locker._lockerObject;
        }

        public static void EndLock(int id)
        {
            lock (DictionaryLocker)
            {
                Locker locker = Locks[id];

                --locker._num;

                if (locker._num == 0)
                    Locks.Remove(id);
            }
        }
    }

    public Entity GetEntity(int id)
    {
        var cacheKey = string.Format(".cache.key.{0}", id);
        var item = Cache.Get(cacheKey) as Entity;
        if (item != null)
            return item;

        object lockObject = Locker.StartLock(id);

        lock (lockObject)
        {
            // all exceptions are handled in this block.
            item = LoadEntityFromDatabase(id);
            Cache.Add(cacheKey, item);
            Locker.EndLock(id);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Changed to `Dictionary`